How can I scroll through the vertical scroll view inside the vertical scroll view in the Swift UI?
The situation is as follows.
There is a custom DropDown Menu button within the vertical scroll view.
If you press the button, you'll get another scroll view
Scrolling is not possible at this time.

private func contentView() -> some View {
        VStack {
            GuideUSearchBarView(currentText: $store.currentText.sending(\.currentText), placeHolder: store.constViewState.placeHolder, lineWidth: 1.4) {
                store.send(.viewEventType(.onSubmit))
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 10)
            
            ZStack {
                ScrollView {
                    wantMoreInfoView()
                        .padding(.top, 5)
                        .padding(.vertical, 10)
                }
            }
        }
    }

private func wantMoreInfoView() -> some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Text(
                store.constViewState.main.styledText(
                    fullFont: WantedFont.regularFont.font(size: 22),
                    fullColor: .black,
                    targetString: store.constViewState.targetString,
                    targetFont: WantedFont.boldFont.font(size: 24),
                    targetColor: GuideUColor.ViewBaseColor.light.primary
                )
            )
            
            HStack {
                DropDownMenu(options: store.dropDownOptions.map({ $0.name }), selectedOptionIndex: $store.currentIndex.sending(\.currentIndex))
                        .frame(width: 130)

                Text(store.constViewState.sub)
                    .font(Font(WantedFont.semiFont.font(size: 22)))
            }
        }
    }


//// DropDownView

@ViewBuilder
    private func ifShowDownView() -> some View {
        if showDropdown {
            let scrollViewHeight: CGFloat = dropDownViewHeight()
            ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                ScrollView(.vertical) {
                    LazyVStack(spacing: 0) {
                        ForEach(0..<options.count, id: \.self) { index in
                            openSelectedItemView(index: index, proxy: proxy)
                                .id(index)
                                .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                                .frame(height: buttonHeight, alignment: .leading)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .highPriorityGesture(DragGesture())
                .scrollDisabled(options.count <=  3)
                .frame(height: scrollViewHeight)
                .onAppear {
                    proxy.scrollTo(selectedOptionIndex)
                }
            }
        }
    }



" ZStack "
I tried to resolve it with Zindex (100) in subview through ZStack.
" .Gesture(DragGesture()) "
I tried to solve this through gestures.

I tried the above method but it didn't work.
